# React countdown using Material UI ProgressBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a functionality where when a user presses a lock button, the item's `isReserved` state becomes true. Once that is done, two more states will be created in Firebase Firestore, `startDate` & `expiryDate`. The `expiryDate` is 72 hours from the `startDate`, which should be mapped to the progress bar. Once the progress value decreases to 0, the item's `isReserved` state reverses back to false in firestore.

The firestore document has the following data

```
reserveDB.doc(item.productID).set({
        productID: item.productID,
        image: item.image,
        price: item.price,
        productName: item.productName,
        isReserved: true,
        startDate: Date.now(), // time saved as timestamp
        expiryDate: event.setHours(72), // time saved as timestamp
      });
```

I was trying out various examples I found on YouTube, but most of them implement the countdown in a day, hours, minutes and seconds format. I tried to to the same, but mine only shows the days and hours remaining. You can view the rest of my attempt at this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-njnjwf?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `setHours` function, get the amount of hours for the current date, and add 72 to that.

```js
  const newStartDate = new Date();

  const getExpiryDate = (date, hours) => {
    const expirationDate = new Date(date);
    expirationDate.setHours(expirationDate.getHours() + hours);
    return expirationDate;
  };

  reserveDB.doc(item.productID).set({
    productID: item.productID,
    image: item.image,
    price: item.price,
    productName: item.productName,
    isReserved: true,
    startDate: newStartDate,
    expiryDate: getExpiryDate(newStartDate, 72),
  });
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but the issue I have is to make the `ProgressBar` countdown from the `expiryDate` to the 0.